# Rails - Polymorphism in single table inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism, single-table-inheritance

I have three models, `Poem` and `Song` and `User`.
Users can vote on any number of poems and songs.

One solution would be to make two association models `PoemVote` and `SongVote`

```
class PoemVote
  attr_accessible :poem_id, :user_id
  belongs_to :poem
  belongs_to :user
end

class SongVote
  attr_accessible :song_id, :user_id
  belongs_to :song
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I can call `some_poem_vote.poem` and `some_song_vote.song`

However, `PoemVote` and `SongVote` are essentially the same. How do I use single table inheritance to extend the two from one parent `Vote` class?

I'm thinking something along these lines:

```
class Vote
  attr_accessible :resource_id, :user_id
end

class PoemVote < Vote
  ...not sure what goes here...
end

class SongVote < Vote
  ...not sure what goes here...
end
```

How do I make it work so that I can still call `some_poem_vote.poem` but underneath have PoemVotes and SongVotes share one database table? Or is there a better solution for my problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in rails, STI is simple : you just create a `type` string column on your `votes` table, and rails takes care of the rest. To create the right associations, you can do something like :

```
class Vote
  attr_accessible :user, :votable
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :votable, polymorphic: true
end
```

...which would require to add a `votable_id` and a `votable_type` column on your `votes` table. Be sure to add

```
has_many :votes, as: :votable, class_name: 'PoemVote' # or 'SongVote'
```

on your associated model. However, problem with this approach is that you have to be vigilant and not use `Vote` directly to create votes, or you will have votes of the wrong type associated. To enforce this, there is a possible hack :

```
class Vote
  attr_accessible :resource_id, :user_id

  def self.inherited( subclass )
    super( subclass )
    subclass.send :belongs_to, :votable,
                  class:  "#{subclass.name.gsub('Vote','')}"
  end
end
```

... but i know for sure (i struggled with te same problem) that it opens the door for code horror, as you have to resolve a lot of problems caused by inheritance (scopes behave weirdly, some libs don't manage STI well, etc.).

The question is: do you really **need** STI ? if your votes behave the same, don't bother using STI, just use a polymorphic `belongs_to`, you'll save yourself a lot of headaches.

Comment: Got it to work - thanks :)

Used your Vote example and

`class PoemVote < Vote
  belongs_to :poem, class_name: 'Poem', foreign_key: 'votable_id'
end`